# Deserialize GraphQL json with common node element

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Consider the following GraphQL Query:

```
 {
   "data": {
        "products": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "title": "the tittle",
                        "variants": {
                            "edges": [
                                {
                                    "node": {
                                        "id": "The ID",
                                        "title": "The variant tittle",
                                        "price": "0.00",
                                        "sku": "the sku code"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When you create a class structure it's going to have 2 `node` classes with different properties. The first has `title` and `variants` and the next `node` has `id`, `title`, `price`, `sku`.

My guess on how to resolve is to give these different class names:

For the Product Node:

```
public partial class ProductsEdge
{
    [JsonProperty("node")]
    public ProductNode Node { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductNode 
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variants")]
    public Variants Variants { get; set; }
}
```

And for the Variants Node:

```
public partial class VariantsEdge
{
    [JsonProperty("node")]
    public VariantsNodeNode { get; set; }
}

public partial class VariantsNode
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sku")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}
```

This will work, but just wondering if there is a way in JSON deserialization to simplify the class structure and have it ignore the `node` wrapper? Or any other way that I'm missing. Or is this the standard way to address this?

Comment: Have you looked at something like https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/guides/serialization/?

Answer (score 0):

https://json2csharp.com/

suggests:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Node2
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sku")]
        public string Sku { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("variants")]
        public Variants Variants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Edge2
    {
        [JsonProperty("node")]
        public Node Node { get; set; }
    }

    public class Variants
    {
        [JsonProperty("edges")]
        public List<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
    }

    public class Products
    {
        [JsonProperty("edges")]
        public List<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("products")]
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
```

It is basically the same suggestion you made yourself.
But just this when you need to create a C# class of a complex json, it's fast n' easy.